# How to set the toggle of a div element to be first hidden and only after clicked shown?

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle

I am trying this example from w3schools but I would like the div to be hidden first and only after clicking on the button "Try it" to be shown. Currently, it is the other way around

Please check their tiny code and I'd be deeply thankful if you could go through the explanation of the function too...

Thanks in advance for helping this newbie!!!

Here's the link: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_hide_show

Here's the code they use if you rather see it here:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `getComputedStyle()` rather than your current approach of calling `.style`. As stated on the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle),

> The Window.getComputedStyle() method returns an object containing the
>   values of all CSS properties of an element, after applying active
>   stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may
>   contain.

Using `.style` will not allow you to read CSS defined within an external stylesheet, as it can only read [inline style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style).

And now, to answer your question, you can simply set `#myDIV` to include the additional CSS property `display`, and set it to `none`, such that it is not displayed on load.

`myFunction()` will only be triggered when the button is clicked, whereby `getComputedStyle()` will be used to check the CSS properties of `#myDIV`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (window.getComputedStyle(x).display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  <div id="myDIV">
    This is my DIV element.
  </div>
  <p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You set it to be not displayed by default

```
<div id="myDIV" style="display: none;">
This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

the following function

```
if (x.style.display === "none") {...}
```

checks whether your element has the `display: none` tag or not and toggles it - since it will have it at the beginning, it will get removed and the element will appear.

Answer (score 1):

To make it the div hidden first, a little CSS will handle this stuff. Just add `display: none;` to div.

```
#myDIV {
  display:none;
}
```

Now we have to edit a little javascript, if the div display blocks, then make it `display: none;` else if the display already blocks then make it none.

Here is your snippet

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The very simplest solution is to call the function when your page starts up so it will hide it. `myFunction();`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
myFunction();
```

```css
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>
```